# PowerShell - InternetExplorer: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I want to automate the InternetExplorer with PowerShell to open a site in our intranet (trusted sites | protected mode: off)

When I´m executing my code the IE open the intranet site but the reference to the $ie object is lost.

**Error:**
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))

How can I fix this? (Run IE as admin is not a option)

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url)
$ie
```

My workaround, but not so good:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" $urls
Start-Sleep 5
$shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$ie = @($shell.Application.Windows())| Where-Object { $_.LocationUrl -like "*$urls*" }
$ie.Navigate($url2)
```

Comment: I also faced with loosing 'ie' problem when opening intranet sites. This question made me try with Administrator privileges, which is possible in my case, and acceptable.

Comment: i am using the BELT module for this (it works beautifully): http://belt.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does the initial script work for external websites, say google? It works for me.

Comment: Original script worked for me on Win 7 but not Win 8.1, that might be a clue

Comment: Here's a workaround that does not require admin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127120/3196753

Answer (score 4):

Try running PowerShell as an administrator.

Comment: I had a similar issue where the $ie object seemed to "disappear" after calling .Navigate. Running PS as Administrator fixed the problem. Not obvious.

Comment: Running the script as admin is no option for us. Is there another way?

Comment: @Cilvic off the top of my head I would say, no. But maybe this is something you can try in a scheduled task?