# Powershell website login not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a basic powershell script to log into gmail but have some up against a problem. The code is below. I have commented out some bits to narrow things down.

```
$url = "http://gmail.com" 
$username="myusername" 
$password= "123456" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application


$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -m 10000; 
} 

$counter = 0
while (($counter -lt 10) -and ($ie.document -eq $null)) {Start-Sleep 1; $counter++}

$ie.document -eq $null
$ie.Document.getElementByID('email').value=$username
#$ie.Document.getElementByID("Password").value=$password 
#$ie.Document.getElementById("signin").Click();
```

When I run the powershell script, I get the following error.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At J:\scripts\gmail.ps1:21 char:1
+ $ie.Document.getElementByID('email').value=$username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The strange thing is, this was working perfectly fine yesterday and today its not working at all. I am using IE9.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it does work here. However, the "Password" field is called "Passwd" in my case (also testing with gmail). Did you check whether these field names were static?

Comment: Are you sure you're giving your page enough time to load? you have a counter up to 10 that sleep for 1 second, you may have to increase that or remove the counter and make it indefinite until $ie.document does not equal $null

Comment: getting the following error now: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementByID'.
At C:\Users\techjlw\Documents\Untitled1.ps1:18 char:28
+ $ie.Document.getElementByID <<<< ('email').value=$username
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementByID:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 4):

[PowerShell IE9 ComObject has all null properties after navigating to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869518/powershell-ie9-comobject-has-all-null-properties-after-navigating-to-webpage?rq=1) gave me the answer to this. Had to run my script as an administrator due to IE protected mode that was stopping the object from being created. Either turn off IE protected mode or run the script as an administrator to get it working.

Comment: Administrator didn't even help me - had to disable https requirement for protected zones and add the site manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake here:

```
$ie.Document.getElementByID("Password").value=$password
```

The ID should be passwd, not password. So replace that line by:

```
$ie.Document.getElementByID("Passwd").value=$password
```

Works for me.

Comment: I get the error before I even get there. That bit is commented out. I get the error on the login field.

Comment: Strange. I tried your script and it works for me (when doing the suggested replacement).

Comment: Well, sorry to ask a stupid question (but it happened to me ...). Did you do a sign out before trying your script? If you have the "Stay signed-in" option for gmail, your script will never see the login page ...

Comment: Just tried it on a different machine (never logged in) and I get the following error: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'getElementByID'.
At C:\Users\techjlw\Documents\Untitled1.ps1:18 char:28
+ $ie.Document.getElementByID <<<< ('email').value=$username
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementByID:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: The page loads with the login box, waits 20 secs then fails.