# Powershell IE automation losing control

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PS script (2.0) that I wrote that logs into a vendor provided website, clicks some links and scrapes some data and send an email based on that data.

The issue is they upgraded their website. I made some changes, but am stuck on one issue. You used to click a button to enter this website after logging in, but now you click a link.  My code to click the link works, but after that I lose control.  My document appears empty and I can't control it any further.

```
$ie.navigate2("https://ibsbusint.fnfis.com/BLP/NavModelServlet/Interop?appid=APPL00000056&channelName=EG_SSO")
WaitIE($ie)
$doc = $ie.document
WaitIE($ie)
$doc.getElementById("MonitorExtractJobs").Click();
```

The last line does nothing (even though the item exists in the browser). When I look at $doc, all the properties are blank.  Not sure why since I set it after navigating to the new link.

Comment: I recommend looking at Selenium or WaTiN.

Comment: This took months to develop and we aren't about to redo the whole thing. The code above is just a very small part of it.

Comment: You should take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127120/2839376