# Corrupt IE object (IE automation with Powershell)

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation, com-object

I want to automate an accesspoint configuration on the web console with Powershell.

I developed on Win8/IE10 and everything works fine when testing the code.
Unfortunately I received the "productive system" after development/tests.
Now the code should work on Windows Server 2012 R2/IE11.

This is my code for connecting and login to the accesspoint (simplified):

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$IE.Visible = $true #1#
$IE.Navigate("192.168.0.100")
Write-Host $IE.LocationName

$IE.Document.GetElementByID("login-username").Value = "admin"
$IE.Document.GetElementByID("login-password").Value = "admin"
$IE.Document.GetElementByID("login-btn").Click()
Write-Host $IE.LocationName
```

For debugging reasons normally I show the window (comment #1#).
At first Write-Host, the correct location is shown ("Login").
At second Write-Host, the wrong location is shown ("about:blank").
In the IE window you see the right location/tabname ("AP").
Seems like the IE object become unuseable, other properties (like $IE.Document.*) does not work then. I have to close the window manually.

I have two workarounds:

1. When I click (get focus) on the IE window manually before login, it
   works.
2. When I don't  show the windows ($IE.Visible = $false), also
   everything works.

My scenario/tests so far:

1. IE ESC is disabled.
2. I copied the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll from another productive machine (2008R2), so $IE.Document functions would work (dll from my develop machine produces the same error).
3. I tried to enable/disable protected mode (Internet options > Security) for every zone, does not work for me (found on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2rsr8b/automating_ie_getting_strange_behaviour_when/))

Does someone else have an idea to try?
Debugging works with workaround, productive it also works (so far) with unvisible window - but I want to understand the troubles...

Thanks, best regards,
kvo

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue once I deployed my scripts to windows server 2012 which runs on IE11.

The cause for this is losing the handler for the IE object created by Powershell.

I used the following snippet, authored in, [PowerShell IE9 ComObject has all null properties after navigating to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869518/powershell-ie9-comobject-has-all-null-properties-after-navigating-to-webpage) for resolving this issue.

```
function ConnectIExplorer() {
    param($HWND)

    $objShellApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
    try {
      $EA = $ErrorActionPreference; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
      $objNewIE = $objShellApp.Windows() | ?{$_.HWND -eq $HWND}
      $objNewIE.Visible = $true
    } catch {
      #it may happen, that the Shell.Application does not find the window in a timely-manner, therefore quick-sleep and try again
      Write-Host "Waiting for page to be loaded ..." 
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
      try {
        $objNewIE = $objShellApp.Windows() | ?{$_.HWND -eq $HWND}
        $objNewIE.Visible = $true
      } catch {
        Write-Host "Could not retreive the -com Object InternetExplorer. Aborting." -ForegroundColor Red
        $objNewIE = $null
      }     
    } finally { 
      $ErrorActionPreference = $EA
      $objShellApp = $null
    }
    return $objNewIE
  } 




$HWND = ($objIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application).HWND
$objIE.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
$objIE = ConnectIExplorer -HWND $HWND
```